# How do you show that this is tautology? And what is tautology?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

$(p \ominus q) ~\leftrightarrow~ \big((p \wedge \neg q) \vee (\neg p \wedge q)\big)$

I've searched that tautology is the equation being true, but I don't know how to do that. Help please!

Comment: [Truth tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table)

Comment: Make a truth table and if the end result is all 1's, you have a tautology

Comment: In order for this to be a tautology, it has to be true for all possible values of the variables involved, in this case p and q. A tautology is always true, it never gives you any information about the values of the variables involved.

Comment: If you don't know what a tautology is, you won't really benefit from solving a problem that involves tautologies. You need to grab an introductory text into logic and start reading it from page $1$.

Comment: Tautology is, precisely, proposition of the form $\Phi\to \Phi$.

Comment: In logic, a [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)) is a formula that is true in every possible interpretation.

Comment: What does it mean this Ɵ strange symbols ? In the context of propositional logic it does not exist.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I think something like XOR.

Comment: @AndrewMiloradovsky - NO: e.g. $p \to (q \to p)$ is a tautology and also $\lnot p \lor p$ is.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Well, maybe I should add some adjective.

Comment: @AndrewMiloradovsky You probably meant "tautologies are argument of the form 'quadrupeds are four-legged animals'" right?

Comment: @Graffitics No, I probably meant that $\Phi$ is supposed to be up to a definitional equivalence ($\equiv$), in this case the implication lives at higher level. Anyway, for some reason I have a strong association of the term "tautology" with this "tautological implication" expressions, is this just plain wrong?

Comment: @Graffitics For instance, the example above $p\to (q\to p)$ falls in this category ($p\equiv q\to p$), and the other example $\lnot p\lor p$ is true only in classical (binary) logic.

Comment: @AndrewMiloradovsky What do you mean by $p \equiv q \to p$?

Comment: @Graffitics Definitional equality (on function types). But it seems there is something I missed, because as a derivation rule it works in only one direction. The point is that all tautologies may be given that form of trivial implication ($\Phi\to \Phi$), where left and right parts are the same up to a lower level transformation and vice versa, or not?

Comment: @AndrewMiloradovsky I'm sorry, I really don't understand what you mean, maybe its a vocabulary issue and you should ask someone else. The derivation tree of a tautology ends up with identity rules, but the strength lies in the cut rule, which hides the actual complexity of the statement. So if you want to derive Fermat's theorem, the cut elimination procedure is going to run for a long time.

Comment: @Graffitics It seems I really need to think more about it, so I could either prove my initial claim, or maybe post a separate question here. Anyway, thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a truth table for the equation. If the statement is true for every truth value combination of $p$ and $q$, the statement is a tautology.

I'm assuming the symbol you're trying to use on the right side is $\oplus$, which signifies an "exclusive or" operation. The right side of the equation is simply writing the definition of exclusive or: $p$ true and $q$ false **or** $p$ false and $q$ true. If you complete a truth table for this equation you should see that it is a tautology.